# Day’s Theorem for a locally compact group

Tags: convergence-divergence, amenability

The result below is originally due to Day when $H$ is a locally compact group

> **Theorm** Let $H$ be a locally compact group, $H$ is amenable if and only if there is a net $\{f_\alpha\}_\alpha \subset L^1(H) $ such that for every $x\in H$ $$\|f_\alpha-\delta_x*f_\alpha\|\to 0$$

I don't find the original paper

Could anyone please suggest me how to deal with these questions?

Comment: @Dear Tomek Kania thank you very much

Comment: What is $\delta_x$? Point-evaluations are not well-defined for non-discrete groups.

Comment: We define $(\delta_x*f)(y)=f(x^{-1}y)$